# How can I collect custom stats from within my code

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a large bit of code that is made up of many different classes, and I want to build in a means of collecting some stats whilst it is running. Ideally, I want the internal classes to be able to run something like

```
record_stat(:api_requests, 1)
```

The entire process is kicked off from a single entry point (engine), but ideally I'd like to avoid passing that instance around to all of the internal classes. The most obvious solutions (but ones I'd like to avoid) are:

- Pass the instance of the engine itself to all child instances. The engine then has the `record_stat` method
- Return all stats from each child instance and aggregate them within the engine

Initially I was looking at the second option, because I already have a return value class for some of the internals, but I just think it would be so much cleaner to just have a method which handled this without needing to pass things around all the time.

I currently have something similar with logging, where I can run `::Engine::Logger.debug('...')` but that is using `Thread.current` for things and that never quite feels right so not sure if I should do that for this as well.

Are there any ways of making the `record_stat` method available to that process only, or global to a block maybe so that all of the internals could access it and have it unique to that run of the engine?

**Edit: Providing an example**

*Engine*

```
class Engine
  ...
  def sync
    remote = fetch_remote_data
    records = map_remote_to_records(remote)
    save_records(records)
  end

  def fetch_remote_data
    @types.map do |type|
      DataFetcher.new(type).fetch
    end
  end

  def map_remote_to_records(remote)
   remote.map do |r|
     RecordMapper.new.map(r)
   end
  end

  def save_records(records)
    records.each do |record|
      RecordSaver.new(record).save!
    end
  end
end
```

*DataFetcher*

```
class DataFetcher
  def fetch(query = nil)
    provider.fetch(query)
  end
end
```

*Provider*

```
class SomeRemoteServerProvider
  def fetch(query)
    make_api_request.map do |remote|
      <convert to internal format>
    end
  end
end
```

*RecordMapper*

```
class RecordMapper
  def map
    local = find_or_build(@remote)
    assign_attributes(local, @remote)
    local
  end
end
```

*RecordSaver*

```
class RecordSaver
  def save!
    @records.each do |record|
      save_record!
      save_associations!
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

ok so this is a pretty stripped down simplified example, but in this scenario what I'm after is for classes like the `SomeRemoteServerProvider` to report on the number of API calls it has made, or the `RecordMapper` to report on how many local records it has actually found, and how many it had to create. Something like that

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I don't know how to answer this question without seeing any code.

Comment: Record stats from a singleton class? Use the observer pattern? What's wrong with defining e.g. `::Engine::Logger.record_stat`, or `::Engine::StatsRecorder.log`? What do you mean "never quite feels right"?

Comment: @TomLord Can't really provide you with a working example as its huge but I'll edit question to give an example

Comment: A **Minimal** example shouldn't need to be huge.

Comment: @TomLord added an example. When I say `it never feels quite right` I was referring to the use of `Thread.local` specifically. Having static methods is fine, but keeping those static calls in the context of that run of the engine means I need to keep the reference of the engine itself. This would most likely end up using `Thread.local` (as multiple engines could be running so can't just assign to a class variable) and I'm always wary of it as it's essentially global state. But might not be another option

Comment: Good suggestion on the observer patten, hadn't considered that. But how would the initial engine subscribe to events from nested children? In the example above for instance, how would the engine observe events from the `SomeRemoteServerProvider` class when that was instantiated by a different class and not by itself